# Match a value to key value and get key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

let's say I need do this:
I need to match the values in list 'check_keys' against the key-values in dictionary 'parm' and store the matched keys in the same order into a new list 'insert'

```
parm = {'f': 'w', 'l': 'b', 'b': 'y', 'u': 'o', 't': 'r', 'r': 'g'}
check_keys = ['r','b','o','g','w','y']
insert = ['t','l','u','r','f','b']
```

Comment: And what is the general logic behind these list insertions? If there is none, you might as well type the final result in.

Comment: No, the elements in check will be from the key values of parm (this is already validated). I am looking to associate with the right key in before the set of list elements and later I plan to convert them to a dictionary

Comment: The General logic behind is that the parm key value pairs can be different aswell.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at the final result at all. That might be my fault or your explanation needs work - or both. :)

Comment: I apologize, its definitely my fault.
Ill give another example: 
parm = {{'f': 'r', 'l': 'b', 'b': 'y', 'u': 'o', 't': 'w', 'r': 'g'}
In this case check[4] should be compared against all the key values and since it is matched with key 'f', then 'f' should be appended at check[0]

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time but i think i figured out what you want to do.

If i am correct you wan't to reverse look up the dictionary from value to key.
The easiest way would be to cerate the reverse dictionary.

```
rparm = dict( (value,key) for key,value in parm.items())
```

Then match the data e.g.

```
insert = [rparm[key] for key in check_keys]
```

Sorry for using all this list and generator comprehensions. If our are not familiar with them I can add the classic for loop version.

Comment: Thank you!
I get the logic this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is the reverse the dictionary, which can be done in linear time (relative to the size of your parm dict) on average.

Once the dictionary is reversed your searched values become keys 
And are now easily accessible is O(1) per key in your check_keys list.

```py
rev_parm = dict((v, k) for k, v in parm.items())
insert = [rev_parm[k] for k in check_keys]
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your answer to the OP and those who may come across it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @hcoat. Edited in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
insert = []
for k, v in parm.items():
    if k in check_keys:
        insert.append(k)
```

Or this shorter version:

```
insert = [k for k, v in parm.items() if k in check_keys]
```

Comment: This gives an output: ['b','r']
Expected output : ['t','l','u','r','f','b']

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great use of a Hash Table/Dictionary. A Hash Table gives you fast access to the *values*, given the *keys* of the dictionary. Here, you are trying to access the keys of the dictionary, given the values (ie. the other way around).

This is bad because:

- It's slow. You will need to iterate over the entire dictionary to find your values.
- The result is non-deterministic, as dictionaries are unordered. If your inputs were instead `parm = {'a': 'r', 'b': 'r'}`, `check_keys = [r]`, it is uncertain whether you would get `[a]`, or `[b]`.

With all that said and done, this should solve your problem:

```
parm = {'f': 'w', 'l': 'b', 'b': 'y', 'u': 'o', 't': 'r', 'r': 'g'}
check_keys = ['r','b','o','g','w','y']
insert = ['t','l','u','r','f','b']

insert = []
for v in check_keys:
    for k in parm:
        if parm[k] == v:
            insert.append(k)

print insert
```

Assuming, of course, that this is part of a larger program, I would suggest that you do NOT use the above approach, but instead re-evaluate your entire approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *list comprehension* to solve this

```
insert = [k for i in check_keys for k in parm if parm[k] == i]
# ['t', 'l', 'u', 'r', 'f', 'b']
```